# Delphi cannot change listbox item text size

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey

I have a TListBox in my form and I am adding items at runtime like this:

```
ListBox1.Clear;

//don't care about sol, it is a dynamic array with a size between 1 and 6
ListBox1.BeginUpdate;
 for i := Low(sol) to High(sol) do
  begin

   tmp := TListBoxItem.Create(ListBox1);
   tmp.Parent := ListBox1;
   tmp.Selectable := false;
   tmp.TextSettings.Font.Size := 30; //problem here, it doesn't change the text size
   tmp.Text := 'some text';

  end;
 ListBox1.EndUpdate;
```

Here the `tmp` variable is a `TListBoxItem`. Everything is working because I see that when I press the button the listboxes are added into the TListBox.

The problem is that I cannot change the text size. Any idea?
I think that I probably have to set the `StyledSettings` of tmp to false but I am not able to.

Comment: Do you mean you cannot find the `Height` property, or when you change it nothing happens? Also, which version of Delphi? This has been available since *at least* Delphi XE8, AFAIK, but if you are using an older version, it might not have been implemented yet.

Comment: Delphi Seattle here. I need a bigger text font in the tlistbox

Comment: Okay, your question isn't asking about font size. You were just saying "Item size". Font sizes are in the styles, entirely different place. You will have to edit the style instead of the control(s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After reading your question and the comments on your question, it looks like you are trying to set the font size of the `ListBoxItem` you create - and not the size of the `ListBoxItem` itself. So could you please edit your question (title) to reflect that?

The answer to your question is indeed in changing the StyledSetting property of the ListBoxItem - like such:

```
tmp.TextSettings.Font.Size := 30;
tmp.StyledSettings:=[TStyledSetting.Family,TStyledSetting.Style,TStyledSetting.FontColor,TStyledSetting.Other];
```

You'll note that I have taken out the `TStyledSetting.Size` from the `StyledSettings` of the `ListBoxItem`. Please also note that you will have to handle the height of the `ListBoxItem` programatically as well.